# Election schedule

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, election

Is there a set schedule for the moderator elections? 
Looking at the election history, I am guessing it's a two year term, but I have not seen anything that explicitly stated if this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is answered on SE Meta, at [When do moderator elections take place?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99512/when-do-moderator-elections-take-place) Basically, elections are when they're needed, and not on a set schedule.

Comment: I had figured that SE had a rather flexible approach, I was mainly wondering if GIS.se had a formal/informal policy for elections

Comment: @TDavis I did request 2 more moderators for GIS.SE last year (March 2013) hence 2 new mods places (April 2013) purely due to more questions/site traffic was getting demanding for 3 mods. http://gis.stackexchange.com/election - Do you feel the need for more Moderators at this time? Site traffic is increasing daily.

Comment: Related - Averaging 30,000 visits per (week)day http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3629/why-is-gis-stack-exchange-so-popular-of-late

Comment: Just a matter of curiosity. From my own observation so far, it seems like the current moderators are doing perfectly well, and the community in general seems to put a lot of effort into moderation. What was the site traffic like when the mod places were added?